Showing edge relationships by default in memgraph
I am trying to display my graph as a whole in memgraph through query - MATCH (n)-[r]->(m) RETURN n, r, m but turns out this does return nodes and edges connected between them but does not show what relationship is mapped between two nodes by default, just an empty edge. Can someone help with this?
Part of graph for how it's displayed
I tried out multiple different queries and also checked the settings for memgraph instance if there is something to be modified in order to have this shown. I actually did find something but that shows relationship only between two selected nodes when selected show more details but I want this to be shown for the whole graph by defaultSelected nodes relationship display

thank you for asking the question.
Memgraph Lab styles the graph so that the edge labels are not rendered if the graph is too large for faster rendering. You can see this part in the system style:
// Show edge text only if there is a small number of edges in the view
@EdgeStyle Less(EdgeCount(graph), 30) {
  label: Type(edge)
}

To have it shown always, add label: Type(edge) under general EdgeStyle, and remove/comment the above section in the System style:
// Baseline edge style that will be applied to every single edge
@EdgeStyle {
  color: #999999
  color-hover: #1D1D1D
  color-selected: #1D1D1D
  width: 0.3
  width-hover: 0.9
  width-selected: 0.9
  font-size: 3
  label: Type(edge)
}

I hope that helps.
For other questions, feel free to join our Discord server.
